# Android: Always getting GET on the server eventhough POST was sent

Tags: java, android, ruby-on-rails, http, rest

I am trying to send data using POST method from my android apps. However in
the server it is always recognized as GET. I am using Rails apps as the web
service. Here is the snippet of my Android code:

```
URI uri = new URI(hostName);

HttpPost httpRequest = new HttpPost(uri);

 httpRequest.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");

 httpRequest.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

 List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

 pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key1", "value1"));

 httpRequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));

HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpRequest);
```

Have I done anything wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Code looks ok. You sure it's not something on server? Did you check the log on server or you just noticed that wrong method was called?

Comment: I was also monitoring the server log at the same time and it is calling http Get method.

Answer (score 0):

You're android code looks fine, make sure your log doesn't show a 301 redirect code for POST despite showing a 200 code for GET. Strangely, this can be the case depending on your host configuration.
e.g. You might see something like this :

```
123.156.189.123 - - [21/Oct/2011:09:03:34 -0700] "POST /server_script.php HTTP/1.1" 301 532 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.835.202 Safari/535.1"
123.156.189.123 - - [21/Oct/2011:09:03:34 -0700] "GET /server_script.php HTTP/1.1" 200 250 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.835.202 Safari/535.1"
```

Here the GET was not redirected (code 200), but the POST was (code 301). If this is happening then you need to override your redirect settings using a .htaccess or other configuration options.

Answer (score 0):

Were you being redirected? I suspect that if you try to POST to domain A that redirects you to domain B, your request will be turned in to a GET request. I had the same problem until I decided to use the server's IP address in the POST request directly, instead of using a alphabet name that redirects to the IP.

Comment: @MohitJain I'm not sure what you mean by not providing an answer to the question. I mention what might be causing his problem, and what he can do to solve that problem if that is so.

Comment: @MohitJain If you have anything to add, please feel free to do so instead of unilaterally deleting this post.

Comment: I would delete my comment